# Swift Check , Unchecked Button

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have two modified buttons to be a checkbox with a subclass, the checkbox is `siCheckbox` and `noCheckbox`. if `siCheckbox` is checked the other will be unchecked.
The problem is , if i press `siCheckBox` again will set `noCheckbox` checked and `siCheckBox` unchecked

this is my code

```
import UIKit
class Paso1: UIViewController, CheckBoxDelegate   {

    @IBOutlet weak var siCheckBox: CheckBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var noCheckBox: CheckBox!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.siCheckBox.delegate = self
        self.noCheckBox.delegate = self
    }

    func checkBoxDidChange(checkbox: CheckBox) {
        if checkbox == self.siCheckBox {
            self.noCheckBox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked

        } else {
            self.siCheckBox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked

        }
    }
```

and this is the subclass for the buttons checkbox

```
protocol CheckBoxDelegate {
   func checkBoxDidChange(checkbox: CheckBox) -> Void 
}
import UIKit

class CheckBox: UIButton {

    // Images
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "check-greenb")! as UIImage
    let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "check-baseb")! as UIImage

    var delegate: CheckBoxDelegate?
    // Bool property
    var isChecked: Bool = false {
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        isChecked = !isChecked
        self.delegate?.checkBoxDidChange(self)
    }}
```

is there any examples or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your button to change its checked property if it is already checked, just add conditional logic in your `buttonClicked` function.

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if !isChecked {
        isChecked = !isChecked
        self.delegate?.checkBoxDidChange(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit complicate to do this.
What I would do :

```
@IBOutlet weak var siCheckBox: CheckBox!
@IBOutlet weak var noCheckBox: CheckBox!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.siCheckBox.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Selected)
    self.siCheckBox.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)

    self.noCheckBox.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Selected)
    self.noCheckBox.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)

}

@IBAction func checkBoxAction(sender : UIButton) {

    siCheckBox.isSelected = false
    noCheckBox.isSelected = false

    sender.isSelected = true
}
```

That way you don't even need to subclass your button and no delegate to set. Don't forget to link your two buttons to the checkbox action function ;)